# Updating multiple database rows in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

How can I update a set of rows in Orchard?

I have an array of customer ids. And I want to set the IsActive field to No for all these customers.

Do I use ContentManager or IRepository? And do I have to loop through and update each row or is there a way to update all the rows in one statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend **NHibernate Hibernate Query** Language (HQL) for 'batch updates', it makes things more difficult, When Orchard will upgrade it's core to NHibernate 3.2 or higher it will be alot faster, see for more information http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/03/nhibernate-32-batching-improvement.html

If u still want to execute a update statement u can use HQL in your custom repository, there is a protected property in the Repository base class which returns you the NHibernate ISession. Using this NHibernate Session u can Call CreateQuery()

Just remember to use **your classname and propertynames** and not the table names

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update Customers set IsActive = :isActive" +
                                  "where Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,));
query.setParameter("isActive", "false");
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own table, which is not connected to any ContentPart - stick to `IRepository`. `ContentManager` is meant for managing content items.

The way `IRepository` implementation works in Orchard, you need to loop through all customers.